# Bash script that gets title of onion sites

Tags: bash, curl, tor

I am writing a bash script that is given a list of ".onion" sites and cURLs each site for the page title, then outputs in the following format in a new text file:

"Page Title" - "xxxxxx.onion"

Here is the code I have so far, but I am hitting a wall on how to achieve my goal.

```
#
#
echo 'Must have PCRE installed for grep'
echo ''
#
#
# Check for Onion Router connection
#
RESP1="$(curl --socks5-hostname localhost:9150 -s 'https://check.torproject.org')"
#
# echo $RESP1 # DEBUG
RESP2=$(echo "$RESP1" | grep -m 1 "Congratulations" | xargs)
# echo $RESP2 # DEBUG
if [ "$RESP2"="Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor." ]
  then
        echo "Connected to the Onion Router"
    else
        echo "Failed to connect to the Onion Router" 
      exit 1
fi
# Grab raw html of site
RESP3="$(xargs -n 1 curl --socks5-hostname localhost:9150 -so - < slist.txt)"
# RESP3="$(curl --socks5-hostname localhost:9150 "$site" -so - )" # OLD
# Grep for title
RESP4=$(echo "$RESP3" | grep -iPo '(?<=<title>)(.*)(?=</title>)')
#
echo $RESP4
```

Comment: did you get connected? what is the part that's not working for you?

Comment: @lab9 This code is working, I just don't know where to go from here to reach my goal. Im looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems you're almost there.
If you replace the last part of your script with:

```
cat slist.txt \
| while read -r url; do
    # Grab raw html of site
    RESP3="$(curl --socks5-hostname localhost:9150 -so - $url)"
    # Grep for title
    RESP4=$(echo "$RESP3" | grep -iPo '(?<=<title>)(.*)(?=</title>)')
    #
    echo "$RESP4 - $url"
done
```

Just redirect the output of the script to a text file. Is that what you aim at or did I miss something?

Comment: That did it! Thank you for your help!

Comment: How would I make the results save to a text file?

Comment: Redirection in Linux goes like this: `./myscript.sh >mytextfile`, meaning that you use the redirection symbol (__*>*__) to save the output to the file. The double redirection symbol (__*>>*__) would _append_ to that file.

Comment: Is there a way I can make the program run faster? I know that TOR takes a while to make a circuit and connect, but is there anything I can do?

Comment: It's quite certain that almost all time gets consumed by the _curl_ call while waiting for the HTTP response. You could replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` to avoid the DNS call, however that will most likely not make it much faster.